# UnityでPhotonFusion使った同期でのFixedUpdateNetwork()の機能についての質問

Tags: unity3d

UnityでPhotonFusion使った同期でのFixedUpdateNetwork()の使い方についての質問です

ローカルで

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
{
    
    PhotonFusionSpawn.SpawnCheck();
}
```

のような処理をすると

```
    public void SpawnCheck()
    {
        
        spawnCheck = true;
    }

    public void Spawn()
    {

    Runner.Spawn(_prefabBall,
        transform.position, Quaternion.identity,
        inputAuthority: null, (runner, o) =>
        {
　　　　　　　　　　　　　spawnCheck = false;
    });
    
　　}
    public override void FixedUpdateNetwork()
    {
        if (spawnCheck == true)
        {
            Spawn();
        }
    }
```

としてみているのですが、動きません
if (spawnCheck == true)を外してSpawn()だけにすると
オブジェクトを生成し続ける感じになります
UnityでいうとUpdate()みたいな使い方だと思っていたのですが、違うのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします